# How to show only date in DateTimePicker in react native

Tags: react-native, datetimepicker

I am new to react native. I have created a screen where I am showing date . and I am using DateTimePicker in react native. But the problem is I only want to show date like this => "fri jun 12 2020" or 6 jun 2020 or 6/6/2020 or 6-6-2020. but I am getting date like this.=> Fri Jun 12 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530(IST). so please help. thanks. In short I dont want display Time

here is my code

```
<DateTimePicker 
   value={date}           
   mode={mode}
   is24Hour={false}
   display="default" 
   onChange={this.setDate} 
/>

<Text style={{fontSize: 18}}>{String(this.state.dateString)}</Text>
```

here is my code of onChange . I am getting undefined instead of date = >

```
setDate = (event,  selectedDate) => {

    const year = selectedDate.getFullYear();
    const  month = selectedDate.getMonth(); 
    const  day= selectedDate.getDate();
  
    const  dateString = `${day}-${month}-${year}`;
    this.setState({date: selectedDate})
    this.setState({dateString: dateString})

 }
```

Comment: excellent!
But I think you made a typo there
``this.setState({Date : date})``

Comment: No. I think You should check once and try to edit my code please I dont know what to do with that platform.os === ios

Comment: This is how you control the visibility of the state according to the platform

Comment: means I dont get it

Comment: also ``setDate = (event, date, selectedDate) => {``
need to be ``setDate = (event,  selectedDate) => {``

Comment: I still not get it (hahaha). please elaborate

Comment: I edit your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229436/discussion-between-sohil-shaikh-and-yoel).

Answer (score 1):

add state `stringDate`

```
const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {      
  const year = selectedDate.getFullYear();
  const  month = selectedDate.getMonth()+1; 
  const  day= selectedDate.getDate();

  const  dateString = `${day}-${month}-${year}`;
  setDate(date );
  setDateString(dateString) 
};
```

then display `dateString`

```
   <Text style={{fontSize: 18}}>{String(this.state.dateString)}</Text>
```

Comment: please check my updated  onChange code i am keep getting undefined instead of date